# Python, seaborn, statistic analysis using statannot doesn't look right

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, seaborn

I used statannot to perform a statistical test on some basic data, but the results from the statistical test don't seem correct. I.e. a couple of my comparisons come up with "P_val=0.000e+00 U_stat=0.000e+00", which I think should not be possible. Is there something wrong with my data frame and/or code?

Here is the data frame I am using:
[image: DataFrame]

and here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from statannot import add_stat_annotation
import scipy.stats as sp

data = pd.read_excel('Z:/DMF/GROUPS/gr_Veening/Users/Vik/scRNA-seq/FACSAria/Adherence-invasion assays/adherence_invasion_assay_a549-RFP 4-6-21.xlsx',sheet_name="Sheet2", header = 0)

sns.set_theme(style="darkgrid")
ax1 = sns.boxplot(x="Strain", y="adherence_counts", data=data)
x = "Strain"
y = "adherence_counts"
order = ["D39", "D39 Δcps", "19F", "19F ΔcomCDE"]
ax1 = sns.boxplot(data=data, x=x, y=y, order=order)
plt.title("Adherence Assay")
plt.ylabel('CFU/ml')
plt.xlabel('')
ax1.set(xticklabels=["D39", "D39 Δ$\it{cps}$", "19F", "19F Δ$\it{comCDE}$"])
add_stat_annotation(ax1, data=data, x=x, y=y, order=order,
                    box_pairs=[("D39", "19F"), ("D39", "D39 Δcps"), ("D39 Δcps", "19F"), ("19F", "19F ΔcomCDE")],
                    test='Mann-Whitney', text_format='star', loc='inside', verbose=2)
```

Finally, here is the results from this statistical test:

```
D39 v.s. D39 Δcps: Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test two-sided with Bonferroni correction, P_val=0.000e+00 U_stat=0.000e+00
D39 Δcps v.s. 19F: Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test two-sided with Bonferroni correction, P_val=1.000e+00 U_stat=2.000e+00
19F v.s. 19F ΔcomCDE: Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test two-sided with Bonferroni correction, P_val=7.617e-01 U_stat=8.000e+00
D39 v.s. 19F: Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test two-sided with Bonferroni correction, P_val=0.000e+00 U_stat=0.000e+00
C:\Users\Vik\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py:7171: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  z = (bigu - meanrank) / sd
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems come from two parts:

- Statistically, in some of your cases (such as "D39" vs "19F"), all items are larger/smaller in one group vs the other, hence the 0 U statistic and extreme p-value. It is very much possible to have these results. It comes from examining only the ranks of the values provided (what this test does), it has advantages and limitations (+ Mann-Whitney's test is not adapted to such small sample sizes either, especially with `scipy` assuming equivariance).
- Now that line `z = (bigu - meanrank) / sd` failing means that `np.sqrt(T * n1 * n2 * (n1+n2+1) / 12.0)` = 0, so in this case `n1` and/or `n2` are `0`, (these are `len(x)` and `len(y)`). [source in scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.6.3/scipy/stats/stats.py#L7090-L7185) So,

  - There is a bug in `statannot`, because this can happen, silently, if `order` and `box_pair` both refer to a series which does not exist in the dataframe, which I'll correct in `statannotations`. Thank you, then.
  - However, I cannot reproduce your Warning with a copy of your dataframe.
    If this were the only bug, you should see a missing box in your plot at the point you showed us.
    If not, is it possible you updated some of the code but did not copy the last output here? Otherwise, there may be something more to uncover, please let us know.

EDIT: As discovered in the discussion, the second problem can happen in `statannot` if there is a mismatch between a label in `order`, `box_pairs` and in the dataset. This has been patched in `statannotations`, a fork of `statannot`.

Comment: Hey Trevis, thank you very much for you reply!
Unfortunately, the code and output which brings up the Warning in my Spyder console is the exact same as what I posted for this question.

Comment: Hi @VikrantMinhas, did you try using `statannotations` ? you can run `pip install statannotations` and then use `from statannotations import add_stat_annotation` and not change anything else. If the problem persists, is there a box missing on the plot?

Comment: Perfect. Check your dataset and your box_pairs, there is a mismatch, probably an extra space in one case, for `D39`. I suspect you also lack a box in your boxplot.

Comment: Hey Trevis, I added `statannotations` and put `from statannotations import add_stat_annotation` into my code. But it came up with the error `ValueError: Missing x value "D39" in Strain (specified in order)`

I already have 'add_stat_annotation` from statannot in my code. Not sure if this will have an impact on the new code. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes that fixed, thank you very much for that! 
Just fyi, all boxes were present even before with the extra space in my data

Comment: Interesting... Did you apply the `order` argument to `sns.boxplot` as we see above? And if I did answer your question, could you mark it so? Thanks